# How To Sync SQLite From PC to Android

Tags: android, sqlite, synchronization

I have a simple SQLite database on my PC containing one table. I have the same SQLite database in my Android app. The data changes on the PC version of the database from time to time. How do I go about syncing the data from the SQLite database on the PC to the SQLite database on the Android device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple solution with sockets:

1. Server side :

   ```
   ServerSocket servsock = new ServerSocket(2004);
   while (true) {
     System.out.println("Waiting...");
     Socket sock = servsock.accept();
     System.out.println("Accepted connection : " + sock);
     BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(
               new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));
     String serverResponse = input.readLine(); 
     // sendfile
     File   myFile = new File("C://XXXX/XXXX/XXXXX.db");
     byte [] mybytearray  = new byte [(int)myFile.length()];
     FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);
     BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
     bis.read(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
     OutputStream os = sock.getOutputStream();
     System.out.println("Sending...");
     os.write(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
     os.flush();
     sock.close();
     }
   ```
2. Client side :

   ```
       private String serverIpAddress = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx";
   private static final int REDIRECTED_SERVERPORT = 2004;
   InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(serverIpAddress);
   socket = new Socket(serverAddr, REDIRECTED_SERVERPORT);
   int filesize = 6022386;
   int bytesRead;
   int current = 0;
   byte[] mybytearray = new byte[filesize];

   InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();

   BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
   FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(
           "/data/data/XXXXX/databases/XXXXX.db");
   BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);

   bytesRead = is.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
   current = bytesRead;

   do {
       bytesRead = is.read(mybytearray, current,
               (mybytearray.length - current));
       if (bytesRead >= 0)
           current += bytesRead;
   } while (bytesRead > -1);

   bos.write(mybytearray, 0, current);
   bos.flush();
   bos.close();
   socket.close();
   ```

Answer (score 0):

This will take quite some work to get it running without problems. Here is how I'd go:

- Use a receiver on the Android to detect when USB is plugged. When this is detected, copy your database file over to the SD Card in a folder of your choice (say /data/com.example.package/sync/db.sqlite).
- From your PC, detect mass storage devices. Scan the SD Card to check if you find the file at the path above. If not, there is nothing to sync. If yes, then you'll need to perform some DB comparison (google for algorithms and depending on your data you have different possibilities here)
- Now you should be having a 3rd database file (the result of the sync between PC and Android databases). This file can be copied to the mass storage (your SD card) at the same place as it was taken.
- Use a receiver on the Android to detect when the SDCard is mounted. When this is detected, simply copy the database file from /data/com.example.package/sync/db.sqlite to your application package directory.

We did that for a music application. This is not a trivial task but we managed to get it working quite nicely.

Comment: I was hoping that it could be done without having to connect with usb. Also, if I copy it over to the package directory doesn't that place an uncompressed version of the database on the android device? Thanks for the reply!

Comment: You can also choose to create a small http server within you app that will offer the DB file for download to the PC software. You do whatever you want with the DB file, you can compress and encrypt it if you like before the copy (just a few more Java code lines)

Comment: So after a LOT of research I think the best way to handle this would be with a Java Socket in the android app and a Java Server Socket app on the PC on the local network. Both databases in each field will contain a DB version ID. I can then connect from my android device using a Java Socket to my Java app ServerSocket on the PC. From the PC I then query the PC SQLite database for newer data based on the DB version ID from the android SQLite db and send any newer results back. From there I simply Insert those results into the android side SQLite db. One port will need to be forwarded to PC.